vscode UI commit + poetry + pre-commit = [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python'
I get the following pre-commit error ("Errno 2") when clicking "Commit" button in the vscode UI.



git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet poetry_test..............................................................Failed


hook id: poetry_test
exit code: 1

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python'

However, when I run from the terminal the following, all is golden:
pre-commit run


poetry_test..............................................................Passed

Looking at stackoverflow & github tips, I tried re-installing pre-commit and poetry in many different ways, clear my caches and venv, etc, to no avail.
I have a hunch it may be related to a limitation already known in vscode, but i am not sure: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/10165
Would anybody know how to solve it?
What I already considered (selection):

Poetry: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python'
Pre-commit error: cannot spawn .git/hooks/pre-commit: No such file or directory
pre-commit/hook: No such file or directory


For reference, here is my pre-commit config:
repos:
- repo: local   
    hooks:
    - id: poetry_test
      name: poetry_test
      entry: poetry run true
      language: system

And this is my installation script how I set up my environment:
#!/bin/bash

## To run:
# chmod +x setup.sh
# ./setup.sh

# Update package lists
sudo apt-get update 

# Install necessary dependencies
sudo apt-get install -y \
    python3 \
    python3-pip \
    git \
    pre-commit

# Installing Poetry
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -

# Add directory to PATH if not already added
export PATH=$PATH:/config/.local/bin

# Make sure poetry makes virtual env in project
poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true

# Install poetry dependencies
poetry install

# # Install pre-commit hooks
pre-commit install

# Show env info
poetry env info

# Show installation
poetry show

# Open poetry shell
poetry shell


The -1 vote without a comment won‘t help to improve. I spent hours researching trying to fix it, and really don‘t get the vote. Any comment appreciated.
